# Customize Azure API Management Developer Portal

Tags: documentation, azure-api-management

I am Customizing the Azure APIM Developer portal. For the Non Production enviornment like Dev, QA etc I am using the same instance of APIM. But the API name is different. I would like to either group them by name so that I see all the API's related to Dev First and rest of the enviornments later. Is there a way i can achieve it? Also we have one template called API List which we can customize. Can we create multiple pages from this template so that I can create different versions of API List for each enviornment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use tags. You can assign them to APIs and group by Tags in APIs list. Look for this button next to search field:

[image]

if you don't have one, check your customized template, and compare it to default one.

Comment: At this moment, Tags are the only way to go.